Simple question about expectation
I have a question whether given a random variable $X$ such that $P(X ≥ 0) = 1$ and $P(X > 0) > 0$ it is true that $E[X] > 0$? It was mentioned as a remark during a lecture without proof, but I don't see a way to prove it from the definitions (and without using Markov's inequality, since it wasn't introduced yet in my course, and I'm mostly interested in building intuitions/knowledge regarding those fundamental notions).
For simplicity: I'm only concerned about a discrete case. I would appreciate any help!

Hint: in the discrete case you have by definition an $X_n>0$ with probability $p_n>0,.$ If you write down the sum representing $\mathbb E[X]$ and use $X_i\ge 0$ for all $i$ you are done.

If you think of $E(X)$ as the weighted centre of the distribution, since the distribution is never below zero, it makes intuitive sense that the centre is positive. Of course, proving things which are intuitively correct is not always easy. The answer given is excellent.

If $X$ is discrete and $P(X>0)>0$ then there exists some $x_i>0$ such that $P(X=x_i)>0$.
As $P(X\geq 0)=1$, $X$ cannot take on a negative value with a non-zero probability, because the sum of all probabilities must equal $1$.
Thus, we can assume $X$ takes on non-negative values only. If $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots\}$ is the set of all that values, by definition of expectation: $$E(X)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x_k\cdot P(X=x_k)\geq x_i\cdot P(X=x_i)>0$$
